# I can not copy or paste in Debian Remote Desktop Viewer

Tags: debian, ssh, remote-desktop

I can not copy or paste in Debian Remote Desktop Viewer i have tried all the possible combination written in literature, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>right click</kbd>, <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd>/<kbd>left click</kbd>, <kbd>wheel click</kbd>, almost everything written on internet, but no use.

Comment: Please state what software you use for your "remote desktop", what is your client and what is your remote server.

Comment: Remote-Desktop-Viewer comes by default, also copy/paste not working on putty

Comment: using the default "remote desktop viewer" in Debian